# My Provider return a null value despite it exists

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

First I put the code of the classes:

The Home class:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot?>.value(
      value: DataBaseService().events,
      initialData: null,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[300],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home Title"),
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[500],
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(Icons.person),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOut();
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.logout),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: EventsList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The EventsList class:

```
class _EventsListState extends State<EventsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final events = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);
    print(events);
    for (var e in events.docs) {
      final data = e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print(data['eventName']);
      print(data);
    }
    return Container();
  }
}
```

And the Database:

```
class DataBaseService {
  final String? userID;

  DataBaseService({this.userID});

  final CollectionReference eventsCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('event');

  Future updateUserData(String eventName, double cost, String age) async {
    return await eventsCollection
        .doc(userID)
        .set({'eventName': eventName, 'cost': cost, 'age': age});
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get events {
    return eventsCollection.snapshots();
  }
}
```

What am I interested to obtain?
Practically I'm trying to show in my home Page a List of Events (I call the constructor at the end of Home widget). Before putting them into some lables I just tryed to show the results, their values (I print them in the EventsList class) on a terminal ... and it worked.

The results printed at the end of the exception:
[image: The results printed at the end of the exception]

The app shows me the value of the documents on Firebase, despite there is this error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNullException was thrown building EventsList(dirty,
dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<QuerySnapshot<Object?>?>], state: _EventsListState#73d5d):
Error: The widget EventsList tried to read Provider<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> but the
matching
provider returned null.

To fix the error, consider changing Provider<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> to
Provider<QuerySnapshot<Object?>?>.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  EventsList
  EventsList:file:///Users/geremiamoretti/Desktop/Programmazione/Visual%20Studio/star
  ter_architecture_flutter_firebase/lib/screens/Home/home.dart:37:15

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:307:9)
#1      _EventsListState.build
(package:starter_architecture_flutter_firebase/screens/Home/events_list.dart:16:29)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5409:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5297:15)
```

I tried to put question marks all over the place, ma the exception persists.
What do I have to do?

Thank you very mucch.